# Shell script to create one file and append the results

Tags: shell-script

The following script will run every 1 hour. The script creates a new file each time it has run.
The first echo will push header and the for loop will push the results.

But what I additionally want is:

- every day the header should go only once into the file and it should keep appending the for loop results to the same file.
- it should create only one CSV file per day.
- it should delete any old files with name result_ something.

The code I have

```
echo "collectiontime,hostname,diskusage,directory" > /home/result_$CURR_TIME_EPOCH.csv

for i in /data01 /opt /opt/splunk /opt/splunk/var/lib/splunk/kvstore /opt/splunk/var/run/searchpeers /opt/splunk/var/run
do
   T=`sudo du -sh $i 2> /dev/null`
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then   
   T=`echo $T | awk '{print $1","$2}'`
   echo `date +%s`,$HOSTNAME,$T  
fi

done >> /home/result_$CURR_TIME_EPOCH.csv
```

Answer (score 2):

Just test if the file exists, and if not: echo the header:

```
if [ ! -f "/home/result_$CURR_TIME_EPOCH.csv" ]; then 
    echo "collectiontime,hostname,diskusage,directory" > "/home/result_$CURR_TIME_EPOCH.csv"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

As [Ljm Dullaart suggests](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/494033/116858), only output the header if the output file does not exist.

This is a suggestion for general improvement of your script (assuming GNU `awk` or `mawk`):

```
if [ ! -f "/home/result_$CURR_TIME_EPOCH.csv" ]; then 
    echo 'collectiontime,hostname,diskusage,directory' >"/home/result_$CURR_TIME_EPOCH.csv"
fi

for dir in /data01 /opt /opt/splunk /opt/splunk/var/lib/splunk/kvstore /opt/splunk/var/run/searchpeers /opt/splunk/var/run
do
    sudo du -sh "$dir" |
    awk -v OFS=',' '{ print strftime("%s"), $1, $2 }'
done >>"/home/result_$CURR_TIME_EPOCH.csv" 2>/dev/null
```

If you are using `bash`, you may benefit in terms of readability, from using an array for the directories (and a separate variable for the output file):

```
dirs=(  /data01
        /opt
        /opt/splunk
        /opt/splunk/var/lib/splunk/kvstore
        /opt/splunk/var/run/searchpeers
        /opt/splunk/var/run )

outfile="/home/result_$CURR_TIME_EPOCH.csv"

if [ ! -f "$outfile" ]; then
    echo 'collectiontime,hostname,diskusage,directory' >"$outfile"
fi

for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    sudo du -sh "$dir" |
    awk -v OFS=',' '{ print strftime("%s"), $1, $2 }'
done >>"$outfile" 2>/dev/null
```

To delete old files, you could use, for example,

```
find /home -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'result_*.cvs' -ctime +1 -delete
```

This would find and delete all regular files that has names matching the given pattern and that has a ctime timestamp of more than one day ago.  Subdirectories of `/home` would not be searched thanks to `-maxdepth 1`.